# What does "Re-registration pending" status means in bank for ECS?

Tags: india, banking, bank-account, direct-debit

Recently i have provided my [BOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_of_Baroda) account details for [LIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_Insurance_Corporation) ECS. After banking process i got one message from bank site  like :

> policy no xxxxxxx with amt xxx.xx registered for ECS.
>
> debit date will be 07th of every month

But installment not getting deducted on said date. I've contacted to LIC agent, he is saying it require around one month more time and sent me once snap with my details there I'm seeing :

> **Registration Status : Re-registration pending**

I have no idea what's wrong. Who should I contact My Bank or LIC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Who should I contact My Bank or LIC ?

It generally takes few months for the process to be streamlined. Starting point would be LIC. They are the one's that would hold the mandate and send the debit amount for collection. Your Bank can't tell why the debit has not happened.

Comment: Thanks, I was  in confusion with that message, i got on my number that its registered from bank side. let me wait for few more days (until next deduction)